# To_chars in JPA

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I have native query added in JPA and want to format the date as yyyy-MM-dd

```
        select to_char(date,'yyyy-MM-dd') from table1 where date > sysdate;
```

This date data is stored as either varchar or timestamp in different tables. So I converted into  to_char with this format to make it generic. When ran on Oracle DB it worked but when executed on JPA it throws invalid number.

I tried using Operator instead it threw Operator is invalid.

Thanks

Comment: The function is named `to_char` (no `s` at the end) - but it's much better to do formatting on the presentation layer (=UI), not during data retrieval

Comment: You shouldn't do any type conversion, you should do value _formatting_

Comment: "This date data is stored as either varchar or timestamp" - a string value will cause this error, as Oracle will assume you're calling the numeric version of `to_char()`. You would have to convert it to a date/timestamp first, and then format that using `to_char()` - or preferably in the UI rather than in the query, as already said. You can't really have a single generic query to handle both source data types (at least without making it quite complicated). You shouldn't be storing dates or timestamps as strings anyway, of course...